# Parallel als Nomen oder Adjektiv

Tags: verb, sentence-structure, noun

ich wollte einen Satz schreiben, aber kam ein Problem. Normalerweise schreibt man „die Widerstände sind in Reihe" aber „die  Widerstände sind in parallel"

Reihe ist ein Nomen, weil parallel ein Adjektiv ist. Im Buch und auf Website immer steht „in Reihe" aber es gibt kein Adjektiv von Reihe, das ist komisch. Auch gibt es Nomen von parallel, das heißt “die Parallele", aber niemand benutzt das.

Meine Frage ist, was ist richtig, Nomen oder Adjektiv. Warum schreibt man einen Satz mit Nomen und anderen Satz mit Adjektiv?

Vielen Dank

Comment: gereiht oder aneinandergereiht (stehen die überhaupt im Duden)?

Comment: "weil parallel ein Adjektiv ist" should be "während parallel ein Adjektiv ist"

Answer (score 1):

Für diesen speziellen Kontext aus der Elektrotechnik gibt es sehr wohl Adjektive für beide Schaltungen:

"Die Widerstände sind seriell geschaltet." = "Die Widerstände sind in Serie geschaltet." = "Die Widerstände sind in einer Serienschaltung geschaltet."

"Die Widerstände sind parallel geschaltet." = "Die Widerstände sind in Parallelschaltung geschaltet."

Ein Äquivalent zum 2. Ausdruck gibt es meines Wissens für Parallelschaltungen nicht.

Comment: Was soll denn an *in Reihe* falsch sein?

Comment: Danke. Zuerst kam mir die Version ohne Artikel falsch vor, kann aber genutzt werden. Nur ergibt sich dann das Problem, das das dazu gehörende Adjektiv für den Kontext nicht erkennbar ist, weil es nicht vom deutschen Wortstamm kommt.

Comment: Ja, Sie haben Recht. Ich wollte einen englischen Satz auf deutsch übersetzen. Manchmal kann man nicht genau in anderer Sprache übersetzen. Jetzt verstehe ich das Problem.